# Remove string using certain values (-)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, scripting, cut

I have following text

> foo-11.11-fo.o-foo-bar
>
> bar-foo-11.11-22.11

I want to remove last strings that have two "-".

**Expected output:**

> foo-11.11-fo.o
>
> bar-foo

I have tried multiple methods using cut, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo-11.11-fo.o-foo-bar
bar-foo-11.11-22.11

$ rev ip.txt
rab-oof-o.of-11.11-oof
11.22-11.11-oof-rab

$ rev ip.txt | cut -d- -f3- | rev
foo-11.11-fo.o
bar-foo
```

Reverse each line, then use `cut` to select all fields except first two and then reverse the output again

You can also use `perl`, but would print empty lines if any input line has less than 3 fields

```
$ perl -F'-' -lane 'print join "-", @F[0..$#F-2]' ip.txt 
foo-11.11-fo.o
bar-foo
```

Specify `-` as input delimiter and then print all but last two fields

Comment: rev that's what I missed. thanks a lot, working great.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/-[^-]*-[^-]*$//' file
foo-11.11-fo.o
bar-foo
```

This will remove `-X-X` at the end of every line in `file`, where `X` is any string that does not include a `-`.

If the strings are in a shell variable:

```
$ s='foo-11.11-fo.o-foo-bar'
$ printf '%s\n' "${s%-*-*}"
foo-11.11-fo.o

$ s='bar-foo-11.11-22.11'
$ printf '%s\n' "${s%-*-*}"
bar-foo
```

or in a `bash` array:

```
$ s=( 'foo-11.11-fo.o-foo-bar' 'bar-foo-11.11-22.11' )
$ printf '%s\n' "${s[@]%-*-*}"
foo-11.11-fo.o
bar-foo
```

This removes anything matching the pattern `-*-*` at the end of the string in the variable `s` through a suffix pattern match/removal. In the case where `s` in an array, the removal is done on all elements of the array.